# How getServlet request dispatcher by URL?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to populate some request with data and redirect back. Is there Spring RedirectAttributes analog for Java EE? I have searched and found 2 solutions, but they also have limitation:

**Response.sendRedirect()**

In this case I will lost all destroys request attributes. I can use Session attributes but in this case I need some mechanism that can determine when redirect comes in or when there is no redirect and data must be removed.

**getRequestDispatcher(String path).forward(request,response)**

The problem with *path* - I need to send redirect to URL not to give something jsp or Servlet by name. Is there any way to "convert" redirect URL to path? For example how I can go forward to

```
"http://localhost:8080/WebAppname/"?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sendRedirect and pass the parameters as part of the query string. So what you would be redirecting can be something like below

```
http://localhost:8080/WebAppname/myRedirect.action?param1=value1&param2=value2
```